# Dependency issue in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just created a new directive, however the console is giving me an error. I believe there is a problem with dependencies as the directive is unable to see a method within the controller.

How can i fix this?

**Error message:**

> Error: $scope.resetMessages is not a function

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('modulename').controller('controllerName', ['$scope', '$location', 'Global', 'Company', function ($scope, $location, Global, Company) {

    /* A bunch of declarations and methods... */

    $scope.resetMessages = function() {
      $scope.errorMessage = null;
      $scope.successMessage = null;
    };

}]);
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('modulename').directive('directiveName', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
        scope: {
            'Company': '&',
            'Global': '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {

             /*
               A bunch of methods...       
              */  

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please create a fiddle or a plunkr illustrating your issue, this code does not even show a call to `$scope.resetMessages`

Comment: `scope: {}` creates an isolated scope. To access something in the parent scope, you can use `$parent`, but try to avoid that as it couples the directive to its parent.

Comment: @AnthonyChu can't i just somehow access $scope, $location, Global, and  Company directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anthony Chu alluded to, this section creates an isolated scope:

```
    scope: {
        'Company': '&',
        'Global': '&'
    },
```

That means it does NOT prototypically inherit from the parent scope, although the parent scope is available via `$parent` although, as Anthony mentions, this isn't a great idea because it creates coupling between the two, which you are presumably trying to sever with an isolated scope in the first place.

You shouldn't need an isolated scope at all in this case. To get access to Company and Global (both available in the Controller via dependency injection) you can just inject them into your directive too:

```
angular.module('modulename').directive('directiveName', 
    ['Global', 'Company', function (Global, Company) {
        // Return directive config here
    }]);
```

Then you can omit `scope: (anything)` in the directive completely, and it will be the SAME scope as the controller, or if necessary, you can do `scope: true` to get a new scope that DOES prototypically inherit from the parent. In either case, `$scope.resetMessages()` would be available.

Here is a [handy cheat sheet to the different directive scope options](http://returnnull.com/blog/angularjs-directive-scopes/).